# c program crashes when retrieving sizeof(buff)

Tags: c, pthreads

I am creating a program in C that splits a large text file into 10 segments, and then creates 10 threads with each thread generating a word count for each segment. I took the function `word_count` from this code: https://github.com/prateek-khatri/seaOfC/blob/master/frequencyMultiThread.c. That program works fine for me, but when I tried to use `word_count` in my own program, it crashes when trying to get the size of the buffer.

It seems like everything is ok in the function `getCurrentSegmentWordcount`, but when that function calls `word_count`, it crashes (segmentation fault) at the line `printf("sizeof Buff: %d", sizeof(buff));`.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define NUMBER_OF_THREADS 10

//struct taken from reference:
struct return_val{
    char wordlist[100][100]; //[chars][lines]
    int count[100];
} *arr; //array of words

void *print_hello_world(void * tid)
{
    //This function prints the thread’s identifier and then exits.
    printf("Hello World. Greetings from thread %d\n", tid);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *word_count(void* num)
{ 

    int *ln = num;
    unsigned int line_number = *ln;
    //line_number++;

    printf("Thread %d\n",line_number);

    char cmd_p1[9] = "sed -n '\0";
    char cmd_p2[2];
    sprintf(cmd_p2,"%d",line_number); //stores string in buffer
    char cmd_p3[21] = "p' 'maintainers.txt'\0";
    char command[100];
    command[0] = '\0';

    //char * strcat ( char * destination, const char * source );
    //appends a copy of source to destination
    strcat(command,cmd_p1);
    strcat(command,cmd_p2);
    strcat(command,cmd_p3);
    usleep(line_number);

    char cmd[100] = " | tr [:space:] '\\n' | grep -v '^\\s*$' | sort | uniq -c | sort\0";
    strcat(command,cmd);
    printf("Command: %s\n",command);
    //fflush(stdout);



    FILE *in;
    in= popen(command, "r"); //read command and pipe into the shell
    rewind(in); //set file position to beginning of 'in'
    char buff[50];
    int counter = 0;


    //char * fgets ( char * str, int num, FILE * stream );
    //reads chars from stream and stores them as string into buff until all of buffer has been read
    printf("before\n");
    bool testBool = fgets(buff,sizeof(buff),in);
    printf("testBool: %d\n", testBool);


    //CRASH HAPPENS HERE:
    //buff 
    printf("sizeof Buff: %d", sizeof(buff));


    while(fgets(buff,sizeof(buff),in))
    {
        printf("fire 0.5");
        char c=' ';
        int i = 0;
        int cnt = atoi(buff); //converts string to int.. buff == # of chars in file?
        arr[line_number-1].count[counter] = cnt; //at this point line_number == 1
        printf("fire1\n");

        while(c!='\0')
        {
            c=buff[i];
            buff[i]=buff[i+6];
            i++;
        }


        int cnnt = 0;
        while(c!=' ')
        {
            c = buff[cnnt];
            cnnt++;
        }
        i=0;
        while(c!='\0')
        {
            c=buff[i];
            buff[i]=buff[i+cnnt];
            i++;
        }
        sprintf(arr[line_number-1].wordlist[counter],"%s",buff);
        printf("%d %s",arr[line_number-1].count[counter],arr[line_number-1].wordlist[counter]);
        counter++;
    }
    printf("final count: %d", counter);
    arr[line_number-1].count[counter] = -1;


    fclose(in);



    //pthread_exit(NULL); //didn't help to move here from getCurrentSegment...()
    return NULL;
}



void *getCurrentSegmentWordcount(void * tid) { //declaring file pointer (value?)
    int segment = tid;
    segment = segment + 1; //converts to int
    printf("segment/thread: %d \n", segment);
    char text[1000];
    //char buffer[150];
    FILE *fp = fopen("words.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL) {
        printf("null file");
    }
    int i = 0;

    long lSize;
    char *buffer;
    if( !fp ) perror("words.txt"),exit(1);

    fseek( fp , 0L , SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell( fp );
    rewind( fp );

    buffer = calloc( 1, lSize+1 );
    if( !buffer ) fclose(fp),fputs("memory alloc fails",stderr),exit(1);

    if( 1!=fread( buffer , lSize, 1 , fp) )
      fclose(fp),free(buffer),fputs("entire read fails",stderr),exit(1);

    //printf(buffer);

    char *token = strtok(buffer, "~");

    if(segment == 1) {
        printf("segment 1: %s", token);
        word_count(&segment);
    }

    if(segment == 2) {
        token = strtok(NULL,"~");
        printf("segment 2: %s", token);
    }

    if(segment == 3) {
        token = strtok(NULL,"~");
        token = strtok(NULL,"~");
        printf("segment 3: %s", token);
    }

    if(segment == 4) {
        token = strtok(NULL,"~");
        token = strtok(NULL,"~");
        token = strtok(NULL,"~");
        printf("segment 4: %s", token);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    free(buffer);
    //pthread_exit(NULL);//moving to end of word_count()
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //The main program creates x threads and then exits.
    pthread_t threads[NUMBER_OF_THREADS];
    int status, i;

    for(i=0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++) {
        printf("Main here. Creating thread %d\n", i+1);
        status = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, getCurrentSegmentWordcount, (void * )i);
        if (status != 0) {
            printf("Oops. pthread create returned error code %d\n", status);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    sleep(8);
    exit(NULL);
}
```

Output:

```
Main here. Creating thread 1
Main here. Creating thread 2
segment/thread: 1 
Main here. Creating thread 3
segment 1: test(segment 1, handled my thread 1)
Thread 1
Main here. Creating thread 4
Command: sed -n '1p' 'maintainers.txt' | tr [:space:] '\n' | grep -v '^\s*$' | sort | uniq -c | sort
Main here. Creating thread 5
segment/thread: 2 
before
segment/thread: 4 
Main here. Creating thread 6
segment 4: 
test test test test (segment 4, handled by thread 4)
Main here. Creating thread 7
segment 2: 
test test (segment 2, handled by thread 2)
Main here. Creating thread 8
Main here. Creating thread 9
Main here. Creating thread 10
segment/thread: 3 
segment 3: 
test test test (segment 3, handled by thread 3)
segment/thread: 10 
segment/thread: 9 
segment/thread: 8 
segment/thread: 5 
segment/thread: 6 
segment/thread: 7 
testBool: 1
Makefile:20: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: the posted code causes the compiler to output LOTS of warning messages, several of which are critical.  When compiling always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Please correct the code and post a EDIT with the corrected code.

Comment: regarding: `printf("Oops. pthread create returned error code %d\n", status);`  1) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  2) when the error is from a system function, also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Typical code would be; `perror( "pthread_create failed" );`

Comment: regarding: `exit(NULL);`  the function `exit()` expects a integer parameter, not a pointer like NULL.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: ( malloc, calloc, realloc ) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling `fseek()`, `ftell()`,  always check (!=-1) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.* 2) separate code blocks ( `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default`) via a single blank line  3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)

Comment: when calling `strtok()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: this kind of statement: `int segment = tid;` is assigning a `void*` to an `int`

Comment: when a parameter to a function is not used, either remove that parameter or the first statement in the body of the function should be: `(void)parametename;`

Comment: the `main()` function is starting several threads, then immediately exiting.  The process of exiting also eliminates the threads  Suggest:  in `main()` calling `pthread_join()` for each thread.  in the thread, at the end, call `pthread_exit()`

Comment: the header file: `stdlib.h`, which exposes the prototype for `exit()` also defines: `EXIT_FAILURE` and `EXIT_SUCCESS`  Suggest using those defines when calling `exit()`

Comment: @user3629249 at this point it will be better if you write an answer instead of writing separate comments. You have enough comments to formulate an answer.

Comment: Can you pass in &i as the last parameter of pthread_create? And then accommodate it with an int *seg variable in the getCurrentSegmentWordcount routine, before assigning to int segment. Program seems to complete its run with this change.

Comment: in function: `print_hello_world()`,  this line: `printf("Hello World. Greetings from thread %d\n", tid);  is trying to print a `void*` as if it were an `int`.  Suggest passing the `tid` as an `int` rather than as a `void*`

Comment: @Pablo,  So far, I have not yet determined the root cause of the seg fault event.  Although I suspect the root problem is that the pointer: `arr` is never actually set to point to any owned memory.  Using it results in undefined behavior and that can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: @user3629249 I think that even if you are not completely sure why it fails, you've gather enough wrong doings of this code that will help the OP and others find the error. I'm afraid that writing 20 comments on these different things will ultimately be ignored as the SO software will hide them from view unless you click on "show more". So all your hard work will be for naught.

Comment: @Snohdo,  There is the problem with your suggestion, that the variable `i` is changing and when the thread processes that variable is not deterministic.

Comment: There are plenty more problems with the code, including the function: word_count()` is only called when the 'segment' is 1

Comment: Really appreciate the comments made by everyone. I will try to clean up the code and reduce the warnings

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues with this code, some have been already mentioned by
[user3629249](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3629249/user3629249), so I'll try to summarize the errors here.

Passing `(void * )i` for the argument for the thread is rather ugly. Sure it
works but this is for me sloppy programming, I'd declare an `int` array and fill
it with the id values and pass a pointer to the locations.

```
int ids[NUMBER_OF_THREADS];

for(i=0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++) {
    ids[i] = i+1;
    status = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, getCurrentSegmentWordcount, ids + i);
    ...
}
```

and then in the thread function:

```
void *getCurrentSegmentWordcount(void * tid) { //declaring file pointer (value?)
    int segment = *((int*) tid);
    // segment = segment + 1; not needed anymore
    ...
}
```

This code is more clean, easier to understand for you and for the code reviewer,
does not relay on ugly unnecessary casts and is more portable.

Same thing with

```
void *print_hello_world(void *tid)
{
    //This function prints the thread’s identifier and then exits.
    printf("Hello World. Greetings from thread %d\n", tid);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

This is uggly, you are trying to pass a pointer as an `int`. The size of a
pointer may not be the same as the size of an `int`. Using the same way of
passing a pointer to int (like for `getCurrentSegmentWordcount`):

```
void *print_hello_world(void *tid)
{
    //This function prints the thread’s identifier and then exits.
    printf("Hello World. Greetings from thread %d\n", *((int*) tid));
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

---

Write error messages to `stderr`. This `FILE` buffer is opened for that reason,
that's what people expect from programs to do. When you execute a program, you
can do this:

```
$ program 2>/tmp/error.log

or this

$ program 2>/dev/null | some_other_tool
```

so that you can separate the normal output from the error outputs.

And when a system function fails, the `errno` variable is set to the error code.
You can use `perror` for a standard error message or if you want a custom one,
use `strerror`:

```
pid_t p = fork();

if(p < 0)
{
    perror("fork failed");
    // or
    fprintf(stderr, "Error while executing fork: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return; // or exit or whatever
}
```

---

You can write code in one line if you want to enter the C obfuscated contest,
otherwise don't do that. It's hard to read for you, it's hard to read for the
code reviewer/co-worker/superior. You gain nothing from it.

Instead of

```
if( !buffer ) fclose(fp),fputs("memory alloc fails",stderr),exit(1);
```

do

```
if(buffer == NULL)
{
    fclose(fp);
    fputs("memory alloc fails", stderr);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); // or exit(your_exit_status)
}
```

It's easier to read for everyone.

---

You should always check the return value of functions that return a pointer.
Check the return value of `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`, `strtok`, etc.

```
if(segment == 2) {
    token = strtok(NULL,"~");
    printf("segment 2: %s", token);
}
```

If `strtok` returns `NULL`, then the `printf` line yields undefined behaviour.
See [3.5.3.3 comment 2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.5.3.3p2):

> [3.5.3.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.5.3.3):
>
> Synopsis
>
> ```
>       #define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
>       #include <stdio.h>
>       int printf_s(const char * restrict format, ...);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> <sup>2</sup> format shall not be a null pointer. The `%n` specifier (modified or not by flags, field width, or precision) shall not appear in the string pointed to by format. **Any argument to `printf_s` corresponding to a `%s` specifier shall not be a null pointer**.
>
> [...]
>
> <sup>4</sup> The `printf_s` function is equivalent to the `printf` function except for the explicit runtime-constraints listed above.

Some libc implementation may forgive you to pass `NULL` to `printf` with `%s`
and print `(null)`, but this is not portable and is undefined behaviour. So you
can only do the `printf` **if `token` is not `NULL`**.

---

The `word_count` function is a little bit horrible, specially how you construct
the commands.

```
char cmd_p1[9] = "sed -n '\0";
```

can be rewritten as

```
char cmd_p1[] = "sed -n '";
```

This will create a `char` array with the correct amount of bytes and initialize
it with a valid 0-terminated string, no need to add the '`\0`' yourself.

The commands that are the same, meaning that they don't need a value from a
variable can be store in a `char[]` or even in a `const char*`. Then construct
the whole thing with `snprintf` and `sprintf`, less lines, less mistakes:

```
void *word_count(void* num)
{
    ...
    const char *pipe_cmd = "| tr [:space:] '\\n' | grep -v '^\\s*$' | sort | uniq -c | sort";
    const char *format = "sed -n '%dp' 'maintainers.txt' %s";

    int cmd_size = snprintf(NULL, 0, format, line_number, pipe_cmd);

    char *command = malloc(cmd_size + 1);
    if(command == NULL)
        return NULL;

    sprintf(command, format, line_number, pipe_cmd);

    ...

    FILE *in;
    in= popen(command, "r");
    free(command);
    ...
}
```

Also note that

```
char cmd_p2[2];
sprintf(cmd_p2,"%d",line_number); //stores string in buffer
```

will overflow the buffer if the line number is greater than 9.

---

```
bool testBool = fgets(buff,sizeof(buff),in);
printf("testBool: %d\n", testBool);
```

`fgets` returns a pointer to `char`, not a `bool`. The `printf` will print the
value of a pointer as an integer. A pointer size is not necessarily the same as
an `int` size, in fact on my system a pointer is 8 bytes long, `int` is 4 bytes
long. You should do:

```
if(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in))
    puts("fgets success");
```

---

```
//CRASH HAPPENS HERE:
//buff 
printf("sizeof Buff: %d", sizeof(buff));
```

1. It won't crash because of the `sizeof`. `sizeof` is evaluated at compile time,
   not at run-time.
2. The `sizeof`-operator returns a `size_t`.
3. `%d` is not the correct specifier for `size_t`, `%lu` is, it should be

   ```
   printf("sizeof buff: %lu\n", sizeof buff);
   ```
4. It will most probably crash because of all the undefined behaviour before
   this point.

---

```
arr[line_number-1].count[counter] = cnt;
```

In your whole code, `arr` is uninitialized, so you are accessing a value
through an uninitialized pointer. That's undefined behaviour and might lead to a
segfault.

---

I want to quote [user3629249](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3629249/user3629249) here:

> *[user3629249](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3629249/user3629249) wrote*:
>
> the `main()` function is starting several threads, then immediately exiting. The process of exiting also eliminates the threads Suggest: in `main()` calling `pthread_join()` for each thread. in the thread, at the end, call `pthread_exit()`

---

Please don't ignore compiler warnings, they are not there to annoy you, they are
there to help you. They are a hint that what you are doing may not be what you
really want. Undefined behaviour, segfaults etc. are often a consequence of
that. So heed warnings of the compiler and when you see one, look at your code,
try to understand it and fix it. If you don't understand the warning, you can
come here and ask a question about it. But having thousand of warning and
ignoring them will lead to headaches and quite franky a lot of wasted time on
your side and ours.

So, please fix all this warnings and details, look at the warning messages of
the compiler and the code might run without problems.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions @Pablo, I will look at all of these, and try to look closer at the warning next time